# Will bigger Micro SD slow down mobile

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, external-sd

I have Karbonn A5+ Android phone running (stuck at) Gingerbread. I want to buy a micro sd card for it and I want to get max speed out of it.

My mobile has 1GHz single core processor.

- Will [SanDisk Ultra Class 10](http://www.flipkart.com/sandisk-memory-card-mobile-ultra-32-gb-class-10/p/itmdadhjnz3ahvc8?pid=ACCDADHFVHVHJZPN&icmpid=reco_pp_hSame_memory_card_3_nr) give me max performance?
- Or are there any internal limitations/specs to mobiles that just constrain the use of all speed that micro sd card has to offer.
- Also, will bigger sizes (32 GB) slow down my mobile?
- And there is this another breed [Mobile Ultra](http://www.flipkart.com/sandisk-memory-card-mobile-ultra-32-gb-class-6/p/itmd6kq4hfbnfndz) class 6 but with speed up to 30 Mbps! What should I go for?

Comment: You should not go below class 4. Class 6 however should be fine. I doubt that your device could really make use of the "additional benefit" of a class 10 card. And as long as your device supports a 32GB card: Size of the card should not slow it down. Just if you fill a bigger size with plenty of (media) files, you might notice the Media Scanner will take a little longer when indexing them ;)

Comment: The "mobile ultra" card's claim of 30MBps is probably referring to read speed.  The "Class 6" bit refers to the write speed (i.e. under worst-case circumstances, the card should be able to write data at a minimum of 6MBps), class 10 and class 4 mean the same, only 10MBps and 4MBps respectively.  It says nothing about read speed.

Comment: As for "internal limitations", SDHC limits the size of the card to 32GB.  64GB and larger requires SDXC support, which ups the limit to 2TB.  Also, processor speed can limit the use of the card, but that shouldn't be relevant to your device.  I've only seen older, low-end devices (e.g. HTC Wildfire S) getting bottlenecked by the processor rather than the SD card.

Comment: @Izzy so why u think my device will not get any additional benefit from class 10, when should one go for class 10? Only for Cams?

Comment: You will only see faster loading times on apps stored on sdcard as the benefit. Also, if your phone does not support class10 spec, then its just useless. I recommend you to get a class6 for compatibility and price sake.

Comment: @forums How can I know if my device supports class 10 card?If it does not support class 10, then what will happen, will it not detect the memory card altogether or just provide lower class speeds?

Comment: Class10 cards operate at 100Mhz and above unlike class6 and below (25Mhz) [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#UHS_Speed_Class). If the card does not support class10 spec then you will get lower performance or even mediocre performance if the card readers timing cant cope up as evident with the discussion [here](http://maemo.org/community/maemo-users/n900_microsd_card_i-o_errors_and_corruption/), they fixed it by hacking the driver. Fortunately new phones (particularly multicores) do not suffer this issue. How can you know if yours is supported? 2011 and newer supports it.

Answer (score -1):

MicroSD cards (Virtually) do not increase performance. They only increase the amount of data you can store. Your phone can go up to 32Gb but most people will not need that. Go with the cheaper one since you will not notice a performance hit.

Comment: You are correct, but there is the possibility he is using a custom rom that has an EXT3/4 partition mimicking internal memory, then go for a faster read speed card as it will affect the OS speed. Under normal circumstances there's no apreciable difference as you said.

Comment: If you're opening Gallery & R/W speed of MicroSD is low, you'll seriously have performance issue..