# What is the storage constraint for Micro SD cards on the LG Optimus L7 II

Tags: external-sd, storage, lg-optimus-l7-2

What is the maximum capacity of the Micro SD card that the LG Optimus L7 II can accommodate?

According to the following review it's 32GB
[LG Optimus L7 II & L2 II available next week](http://ausdroid.net/2013/07/19/lg-optimus-l7-ii-l2-ii-available-next-week/)

Is this accurate? I would much prefer to put 64GB in there. Is there any disadvantage to using the largest Micro SD card I can find.

I found the following question on this site

[Will bigger Micro SD will slow down mobile](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41096/will-bigger-micro-sd-will-slow-down-mobile)

The answer to the question states that the phone in question can go up to 32GB, is this a coincidence or do most or all android phones have this limitation.

The product page on the LG site doesn't seem to indicate what the limit is or if there is one.

[LG OPTIMUS L7 II](http://www.lg.com/uk/mobile-phones/lg-P710)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32GB is the maximum capacity for a card following the SDHC standard found in version 2.0 of the SD standard.  Cards larger than that are SDXC cards.

Unlike the compatibility issue between SDSC and SDHC, An SDXC card is likely to work on an SDHC device, especially if you reformat the card to use the FAT32 file system, rather than the default exFAT, though a high performance card (e.g. UHS) will be limited to SDHC levels of performance.

Comment: So I need to determine whether the LG Optimus L7 II is an SDHC device or not?

Comment: Basically.  From what I can find, it appears to only have SDHC support.  Barring testimonials from other users, the only way to find out would be to try it with a 64GB card.

Comment: Where did you find that the LG Optimus L7 II is an SDHC device? I tried a 64GB SD card and it said "unrecognised file system" when I tried to mount it. Previously I had used the SD card on a windows machine, so I know that it does have data on it and is readable. Might it be the exFAT formatting you mentioned? How can one tell what format the SD card has?

Comment: Yup, it's tripping over the exFAT filesystem.  What you need to do is to reformat the SD card as FAT32, either on the phone itself if it will do it, or on a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of devices limit you to formatting 32 GB blocks if you format in FAT32 or will not format because the partition is "too large".  If you run into that problem, use [this utility](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/discwizard/) to format it on your PC.